# xamarin : System.TypeLoadException: Could not resolve type with token 01000017

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

I have a Xamarin Forms solution which contains in each project.i am getting this error. please help ... thanks in advance

```
public partial class App : Application
{
 AlarmAccount_Loggly _AlarmAccount_Loggly = new AlarmAccount_Loggly();       
    public App()
    {            
            var logTransport = LogTransport.Http;
            _AlarmAccount_Loggly.SendWithSpecificTransport(logTransport);
        }
```

Comment: where are you getting this exception? this error seems to be because you are missing some library reference

Comment: yes prashanth thanks for your response. i have updated the reference.